# create a new column from 3 existing columns (python pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, feature-engineering

I want to create a new column called ('Zoning Status) from the selection of 3 columns, namely the column (RT, RW, Kelurahan). For example, you want to search for Kelurahan 'Batu Ampar', RT 12 RW 2, RT 15 RW 5, RT 7 RW 4. Then the value will be zonasi_1 in the column ('zoning status'). Then Kelurahan 'Batu Ampar', RT 1 RW 4, RT 9 RW 3, RT 6 RW 5 then the value becomes zonation_2. Apart from the 2 conditions above, the value becomes zonation_3. I've tried using for and if else but it's not what I expected. sorry if my english is very bad. thank you before

```
status_zonasi = []
for x,y,z in zip(df_51['RT'], df_51['RW'], df_51['Kelurahan']):
    if x in [12, 15, 7, 11, 11, 10, 9 ,14] and y == [2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2] and z == ['Batu Ampar']:
        c = 'Zonasi 1'
    elif x in [1, 9 , 6, 5, 8, 15, 17, 1, 10, 13, 4, 6, 12] and y == [4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] and z == ['Batu Ampar']:
        c = 'Zonasi 2'
    else:
        c = 'Zonasi 3'
    status_zonasi.append(c)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtrT.png)

Comment: Please include a sample of df_51 and the output that you said is not as expected. We need this to understand what is happening.

Comment: ooh thanks for your reminder. I have added the sample df_51 by image

Comment: What about the results you said is not as expected? What is the output of your current code?

Comment: The output is all values in the new column ('Status Zonasi') 'zonasi 3'. There should be some output of 'zonasi 1' and 'zonasi 2'

Answer (score 0):

You can make slices and apply your conditions to assign values like this:

```py
df_51['Zoning_status'] = 'Zonasi 3'
df_51.loc[(df_51['RT'].isin([12, 15, 7, 11, 11, 10, 9 ,14])) & (df_51['RW'].isin([2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2])) & (df_51['Kelurahan'] == 'Batu Ampar'), 'Zoning_status'] = 'Zonasi 1'
df_51.loc[(df_51['RT'].isin([1, 9 , 6, 5, 8, 15, 17, 1, 10, 13, 4, 6, 12])) & (df_51['RW'].isin([4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])) & (df_51['Kelurahan'] == 'Batu Ampar'), 'Zoning_status'] = 'Zonasi 2'
```

Comment: I am very happy that you have helped my question, thank you. It turns out that my previous question lacked detail. My point is how to make RT 12 with RW 2, RT 15 with RW 5, RT 7 with RW 4, RT 11 with RW 4 and so on. Because with the code you just gave, the results did not match my expectations. There are still RT or RW values that don't match what I want, such as RT 7 with RW 5, this should be in zoning 3 instead of zoning 1. So far, that's what really bothered me

Comment: In this case, you need to change the conditions, because right now in your code you have a condition that if RT is 7 and RW is 5 and Kelurahan is 'Batu Ampar', then the status is 'Zonasi 1'.

Comment: I've tried changing some conditions but still not getting the result. Can you help me?

Comment: You can always add conditions separately, for example `df_51.loc[(df_51['RT'] == 7) & (df_51['RW'] == 5), 'Zoning_status'] = 'Zonasi 3'`